# Getting error as "Class not Registered"

Tags: delphi, dll

I am trying to create an `Active X` DLL in delphi.
I have added a TLB file have an Interface with a `CoClass` declaration and I have implemented the interface in some another unit.

The `DLL` was successfully built and registered too.

But, when I am trying to use the `DLL` for creating and calling methods from the another project it is showing error as **Class Not Registered**.

I am trying to get some information about the same but not able to get answer.

Here is a interface implementation code for the DLL:

```
unit uinfComTestProject;

interface
uses
  ComTestProject_TLB;

Type
  TComTestProject = class(TInterfacedObject,ITestComCall)
  public
      procedure CreateAndShowMyData();safecall;
  end;
implementation

{ TComTestProject }
uses
    ufTestProjectForm;
procedure TComTestProject.CreateAndShowMyData;
var
 frm: TForm1;
begin
  frm  := TForm1.Create(nil);
  try
    frm.ShowModal();
  finally
    frm.Free;
  end;  
//
end;

end.
```

Snapshot for the TLB file definition:
[image: TLB Definition having interface declartion]

Method to create an instance of the interface.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LCOm: ITestComCall;
begin
  LCOm := CoTComTestProject.Create();// getting error at this point
  try
    LCOm.CreateAndShowMyData;
  finally
     LCOm := nil;
  end;    
end;
```

Can anyone please help me on same?
Please let me know if had made any mistake in the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A sidenote. If you're registering a library on a system with UAC enabled, you must run the command line as administrator.

Comment: You can do this from the IDE if delphi has been started with admin privileges.

Comment: @whosrdaddy My IDE Is started with admin privilege.
But still it is not able to register the class.

Comment: Don't start your IDE with admin rights. That's just asking for trouble. You'll only discover your standard user bugs too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error simply means that the COM class that you are registering has not been registered in the COM registry. Whilst you might have successfully registered the DLL, its self-registration did not register the COM class.

To understand why your DLL does not register the class requires knowledge of your registration code, which is unfortunately not present in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I Have searched with the class UUID in registry but it is not there.
So,what I can do to make it workable? Can you please tell me?

Comment: You need to register an actual COM server which I don't see that you've done. Exactly how to do that depends on what your goals are. There are different types of COM server. I'm not sure I want to try to teach you all of this complex topic in comments here. I just tried to answer the specific question that you answered.

Comment: Can you please share some links which can help me?

Comment: Do you want an automation server, or just a plain COM server?

Comment: Try a websearch. I did and came up with: http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/master-delphi-7/content/LiB0121.html and http://www.techvanguards.com/stepbystep/comdelphi/server.asp but there are many more.

Comment: thanks David it helps a alot.
Now I can create and access a DLL class and go ahead with the same.

Comment: @AB: and what was the problem?

Comment: @whosrdaddy I was creating a Type library object which is not getting registred in type library.
Then by using the links suggested by david I tried with the com object which makes my things possible to declare and define the interface and respective classes.